# Custom Controls in Google Earth Plugin

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Google Maps (API v3) supports [custom controls](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomPositioning). E.g.

```
var controlDiv = document.createElement('DIV'); 
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
```

Is something like that possible in Google Earth Plugin API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your control in basic html and then position it over the plugin using an iframe shim.

Example: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html

Comment: Thanks, nice pointer, upvoting. I am already using iframe shims for my "dialog windows" floating over Earth. This is unfortunately far less convenient than the approach in Maps but it seems that nothing Map's like is provided in Earth.

Comment: hopefully they add built in support for overlaying html content in future releases.